# Difference between "and" and && in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

What is the difference between the `&&` and `and` operators in Ruby?

Comment: See also [Difference between `or` and `||`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2083112/211563).

Answer (score 401, accepted):

`and` is the same as `&&` but with [lower precedence](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4). They both use [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

WARNING: `and` even has lower precedence than `=` so you'll usually want to avoid `and`. An example when `and` should be used can be found in the Rails Guide under "[Avoiding Double Render Errors](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors)".

Comment: It would be a good idea to specify that one should usually use `&&`, while `and` should be used for very specific cases only.

Comment: From Andrew Marshall's link: "Another way of thinking about `and` is as a reversed `if` statement modifier: `next if widget = widgets.pop` becomes `widget = widgets.pop and next`. That's a great way of putting it, really made it "click" in my head. (And `or` is like a reversed `unless` modifier.)

Comment: Combine this answer with the details of tadman's answer and you get the whole picture.

Comment: because of the lower precedence, evaluations such as `x = true and false` makes x equal to true and `x = false or true` makes x equal to false

Comment: Updated link from Avdi: https://avdi.codes/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/

Answer (score 260):

The practical difference is binding strength, which can lead to peculiar behavior if you're not prepared for it:

```
foo = :foo
bar = nil

a = foo and bar
# => nil
a
# => :foo

a = foo && bar
# => nil
a
# => nil

a = (foo and bar)
# => nil
a
# => nil

(a = foo) && bar
# => nil
a
# => :foo
```

The same thing works for `||` and `or`.

Comment: `a = foo and bar` _and_ `(a = foo ) && bar` proves that `and` has lower precedence than `&&`.

Comment: i don't get it: what is "foo and bar" meant to return?

Comment: `a = foo and bar` is equivalent to `(a = :foo) and nil`. Since the assignment returns a logically true value (`:foo`) then the second part evaluates, which fails, returning `nil`.

Answer (score 67):

The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) says it better than I could:

> Use &&/|| for boolean expressions, and/or for control flow. (Rule of
>   thumb: If you have to use outer parentheses, you are using the wrong
>   operators.)

```
# boolean expression
if some_condition && some_other_condition
  do_something
end

# control flow
document.saved? or document.save!
```

Comment: Actually the [**guide now says**](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/commit/5920497452c1f6f604742a735f5684e86d4c0003) to avoid `and`/`or` completely, and they might have a point. Often their usage in control flow [could be more obviously written with `if`/`unless` operators](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/) anyway (e.g. `document.save! unless document.saved?`)

Comment: @akostadinov in case you weren't trolling: the Ruby Style guide isn't written by the creators of Ruby. Ruby was created by Yukihiro Matsumoto and others, while the Ruby Style Guide was [mainly](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/graphs/contributors) by Bozhidar Batsov.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, thanks, good to know. Sorry for trolling but I'm sincerely confused with some aspects of ruby reality. One thing is sure - every ruby project needs strict style policies to keep the codebase maintainable.

Answer (score 42):

`||` and `&&` bind with the precedence that you expect from boolean operators in programming languages (`&&` is very strong, `||` is slightly less strong).

`and` and `or` have lower precedence.

For example, unlike `||`,  `or` has lower precedence than `=`:

```
> a = false || true
 => true 
> a
 => true 
> a = false or true
 => true 
> a
 => false
```

Likewise, unlike `&&`, `and` also has lower precedence than `=`:

```
> a = true && false
 => false 
> a
 => false 
> a = true and false
 => false 
> a
 => true
```

What's more, unlike `&&` and `||`, `and` and `or` bind with equal precedence:

```
> !puts(1) || !puts(2) && !puts(3)
1
 => true
> !puts(1) or !puts(2) and !puts(3)
1
3
 => true 
> !puts(1) or (!puts(2) and !puts(3))
1
 => true
```

The weakly-binding `and` and `or` may be useful for control-flow purposes: see http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/ .

Comment: "unlike `||`, `or` has lower precedence than `=`" ...now it makes more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

`and` has lower precedence than `&&`.

But for an unassuming user, problems might occur if it is used along with other operators  whose precedence are in between, for example, the assignment operator:

```
def happy?() true; end
def know_it?() true; end

todo = happy? && know_it? ? "Clap your hands" : "Do Nothing"

todo
# => "Clap your hands"

todo = happy? and know_it? ? "Clap your hands" : "Do Nothing"

todo
# => true
```

Comment: Thank you, but how is the precedence of "and" different from "&&"?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon See [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) for a ordered list of operator precedence in Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

`and` has lower precedence, mostly we use it as a control-flow modifier such as `if`:

```
next if widget = widgets.pop
```

becomes

```
widget = widgets.pop and next
```

For `or`:

```
raise "Not ready!" unless ready_to_rock?
```

becomes

```
ready_to_rock? or raise "Not ready!"
```

I prefer to use `if` but not `and`, because `if` is more intelligible, so I just ignore `and` and `or`.

Refer to "[Using “and” and “or” in Ruby](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**and** checks only first condition and gives result
on other hand **&&** strongly checks both conditions and gives logical result.

Comment: This does not agree with all the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is Ruby intention or if this is a bug but try this code below. This code was run on Ruby version 2.5.1 and was on a Linux system.

```
puts 1 > -1 and 257 < 256
# => false

puts 1 > -1 && 257 < 256
# => true
```

Comment: @JakubArnold Sarcasm is never helpful. Examples sometimes are.

Comment: @BobRodes It wasn't a sarcasm. There are 7 answers, 6 of which already have examples.

Comment: @JakubArnold I still found this example helpful.

Comment: I'm getting odd results as well.  v1 = true and false
p v1     # => app.rb: true, IRB: false
v2 = true && false
p v2     # => app.rb: false, IRB: false
puts 1 > -1 && 257 < 256 # => app.rb: false, IRB: false

Answer (score 0):

For me the behavior of `and` as opposed to modifier `if` is preferable if I want to exploit a side effect of the conditional expression - watch the `undefined local variable or method 'y'` in the first attempt:

```
km@latika:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> x=y if (y="hello")
(irb):1: warning: found `= literal' in conditional, should be ==
(irb):1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `y' for main:Object (NameError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> quit
```

At this point though `y` is already assigned, so I restart `irb` to demonstrate my point with a fresh start:

```
km@latika:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> y="hello" and x=y
=> "hello"
irb(main):002:0> quit
```

In my opinion this is the nicest way to override a variable with something not nil (or false, but that is outside the point). Especially if instead of `"hello"` we have `complicated_calculation()`.