# Why does Ruby 1.9.2 give a syntax error for: puts(true and false)?

Tags: ruby

I am puzzled that Ruby 1.9 (JRuby 1.6.6 (RUBY_VERSION == "1.9.2") and Ruby 1.9.3-p125) give a syntax error for `puts(true and false)`.

I don't know why - what is the problem here? How would I write that piece of code correctly? `puts(true && false)` works but is there a solution with `and`?

Example irb session:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > puts(true and false)
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_and, expecting ')'
puts(true and false)
             ^
    from /home/fr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3p125 :002 > puts(true && false)
false
 => nil
```

Thanks to Mladen Jablanović for simplifying the example. The old example was `f(true and f(false))`.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby

Comment: Simplified example would be `puts(true and false)`

Comment: Thanks @Thilo and @Mladen. I know operator precedence but for me that doesn't explain the phenomenon. Thanks for the `puts` example, that's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [operator precedence](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4) in ruby is `&&` before `=` before `and`. So in your example using `and`, it would try to make this (implicit) assignment:

```
puts(true
```

and then combine it with

```
false)
```

via `and`, which causes the syntax error. See a great explanation here: [Difference between "and" and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)

EDIT: I'm not sure if my "implicit assignment" makes sense - think of this statement to make it explicit:

```
foo = puts(true and false)
```

EDIT 2: Remember that a method call is really called on an object. So the equivalent statements for the two cases would be:

```
Object.send("puts", true && false) # this works
Object.send("puts", true and false) # this is a syntax error
Object.send("puts", (true and false)) # works again
```

Not sure if that helps any more - you're right, it's a bit counter-intuitive. My solution is to stay away from `and` :)

Comment: That is so counter-intuitive to me. This implies that `and` has lower precedence than method argument parentheses. Is this just a bug in Ruby or is there a concept behind this that I just don't get yet?

Answer (score 3):

It's all about precedences "and" and "&&" does not have the same precedeces on operands, try using

```
f((true and f(false)))
```

'and' should be used for something like "do stuff A if this worked ok then do stuffs B" and not for strict boolean checking.

```
check_db(param) and connect_db(param)
```