# what is the difference between 'and' and '&&' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “and” and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)

I realized there are differences between `and` and `&&` in Ruby (this was one confusing sentence).

```
@show_votes = !current_user.nil? and current_user.is_admin?
if @show_votes
  #code assumes everyone logged in is admin
end
```

Whereas:

```
@show_votes = !current_user.nil? && current_user.is_admin?
if @show_votes
  #code assumes only admin is admin
end
```

What is the difference between the two operators? I found that they have different operating precedence, but still can not figure out what the real difference is.

(the application was written with Rails. Although I would expect the same to occur in Sinatra as this is most likely something to do with the Ruby language)

edited the code to better reflect the situation.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Comment: Your assumption is somewhat incorrect, but I am neither sure why that happens in your code.

Comment: You can use symbolhound to search for syntax such as `and` and `&&`.

Comment: Instead of doing `!current_user.nil? && ...` you could just do `current_user && ...` since `nil` evaluates to `false` (this is a fairly common Ruby idiom).

Comment: well actually what happened was my colleague was using `@show_votes = !current_user.nil? and current_user.is_admin?` as a variable, and it would return true for logged in users regardless if the user is an admin. when doing `@show_votes = (!current_user.nil? and current_user.is_admin?)` or `@show_votes = !current_user.nil? && current_user.is_admin?`, it will only return true when the user is indeed an admin.

Comment: I think the Ruby style guide https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or is worth checking out about this issue (and how to avoid it).