# 2 Conditions in if statement

Tags: ruby

I am trying to detect if the email address is not one of two domains but I am having some trouble with the ruby syntax. I currently have this:

```
if ( !email_address.end_with?("@domain1.com") or !email_address.end_with?("@domain2.com"))
  #Do Something
end
```

Is this the right syntax for the conditions?

Comment: Looks right, although, you don't need the outer parenthesis. Can you post some more information about your problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rather than an `or` here, you want a logical `&&` (and) because you are trying to find strings which match *neither*.

```
if ( !email_address.end_with?("@domain1.com") && !email_address.end_with?("@domain2.com"))
  #Do Something
end
```

By using `or`, if either condition is true, the whole condition will still  be false.

Note that I am using `&&` instead of `and`, since it has a higher precedence. Details are [well outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)

#### From the comments:

You can build an equivalent condition using `unless` with the logical or `||`

```
unless email_address.end_with?("@domain1.com") || email_address.end_with?("@domain2.com")
```

This may be a bit easier to read since both sides of the `||` don't have to be negated with `!`.

Comment: or, equivalently:
unless email_address.end_with?("@domain1.com") ||  email_address.end_with?("@domain2.com")

Comment: @LucasMarcondesPavelski added above. I tend to prefer `unless` with logical ands rather than ors but avoiding negation is nice here.

Answer (score 6):

If more domains are added, then the repetitive `email_address.end_with?` is getting boring real fast. Alternative:

```
if ["@domain1.com", "@domain2.com"].none?{|domain| email_address.end_with?(domain)}
  #do something
end
```

Comment: Heh, I was just about to post something like this, except my version was the `unless` ... `any?` form. +1.

Comment: I'll bare this in mind if I need to update it with more domains.

Answer (score 5):

I forgot `end_with?` takes multiple arguments:

```
unless email_address.end_with?("@domain1.com", "@domain2.com")
 #do something
end
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
(!email_address[/@domain[12]\.com\z/])
```