# ruby conjunction and union operators

Tags: ruby, authentication

So I have just (accidentally) discovered that Ruby allows the following Syntax:

`if foo and bar`

or

`if foo or bar`.

How (if at all?) is this different from

`if foo && bar`

`if foo || bar`

Are the operators different? How?

Answer (score 3):

> Are the operators different?

Yes they are as per the operator precedence.

> How?

For more information see [**`Difference between “and” and && in Ruby?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby) and [**`Difference between “or” and || in Ruby?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)

Comment: `and` and `or` are short circuit, they just have lower precedence

Comment: @DylanMarkow sorry,I have corrected.. Thanks..