# Ruby expression parsing

Tags: ruby

Why do I get the following error:

```
irb >> x == "AN" && arr.include? ("bar")
 SyntaxError: (irb):80: syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting $end
x == "AN" && arr.include? ("bar")
                           ^
```

But this works fine:

```
x == "AN" && (arr.include? ("bar"))
```

It looks to be doing this: `( x == "AN" && arr.include? ) && ("bar")`. What the ambiguity here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be spacing out your arguments, it leads to confusing interpretations:

```
x == "AN" && arr.include?("bar")
```

The ambiguity is in trying to determine if `("bar")` is an argument or something else.

There are occasions where you can get away with the space, but it's generally a habit you don't want to get into.

Comment: +1 for "it's generally a habit you don't want to get into." While I occasionally take advantage of Ruby's ability to ignore parenthesis for parameters, I find it a lot easier to read the code with them, plus I know the interpreter will honor MY use of parenthesis over its own built-in heuristics. I'm the programmer and it's the interpreter and I don't want it to think different. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`&&` has a very strong precedence therefore `irb` is parsing it as:

```
x == ("AN" && arr.include?) ("bar")
# Syntax error
```

leading to the error (especially because of the space between `include?` and `(`).

You may want to use parenthesis to ensure the correct order for the evaluation:

```
(x == "AN") && arr.include?("bar")
# true / false
```

In this case you can also use `and`:

```
x == "AN" and arr.include? ("bar")
# false / true
```

which [have a lower precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby).

Comment: Using parenthesis to force the order of precedence is better than changing from `&&` to `and`. The code would be clearer with the additional parenthesis.

Comment: @theTinMan, I think that `and` has been built exactly for this type of situations. Using too many parenthesis can be messy.

Comment: Using too many parenthesis is an indicator of messy thinking and that the algorithm needs to be simplified or broken down.

Comment: @Jefffrey , I do not think that `and` was build for such situations. I think it is best practice to use `&&` for boolean expression and `and` for control flow. Some people think you should never use `and` and `or` (https://github.com/styleguide/ruby).

Comment: @spickermann, thanks for the link. Apparently I was wrong. I've "fixed" the answer.