# Responds to method AND is not null check in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm working with a large codebase where I see the following code a lot:

```
if foo.respond_to?(:bar)
  unless foo.bar.nil?
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do that in one line?

[Final Answer]

```
if foo.respond_to?(:bar) and not foo.bar.nil?
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: Other than the trivial case of using `&&` to combine the conditionals?

Comment: For some reason it seems like a code smell to me if you see that *a lot*. Wouldn't it be better if all `foo`s had some implementation of `bar`, even if it possibly does nothing? Or maybe use the visitor pattern if "do stuff" changes.

Comment: @millimoose lol.  Yeah.  Lots of things would be better if <insert some better practice> was used in the legacy code base.  That's why its called "legacy".  :)

Comment: @bitcycle Fair enough. My reasoning was: if you're already going to change all that code, it might be feasible to actually do it right. (Or it might not, no idea what other constraints you're operating under.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line or one method call? `unless` is simply a logically inverted `if` so you can put it on one line like this...

```
if foo.respond_to?(:bar) && !foo.bar.nil?
  # do stuff
end
```

Otherwise you can create a method on `foo` or some sort of helper that makes the checks in a single call.

Comment: `foo.respond_to?(:bar)` come first.. Otherwise there is a chance to get error as **no method**

Comment: Awesome.  I was wondering if it would _have_ to evaluate both before determining the result of the if-condition.

Comment: @bitcycle With `&&`, the second expression won't get evaluated if the first one is false.

Comment: Does it not also work that way if I use the word "and" instead of "&&" ?

Comment: It's *almost* the same. See this other SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ActiveSupport >= 4.0, Object#try will return nil if the object does not respond to the method. As mentioned in the [Rails 4 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-support-notable-changes).

> Object#try will now return nil instead of raise a NoMethodError if the receiving object does not implement the method, but you can still get the old behavior by using the new Object#try!.

So, you could do what you want with `unless foo.try(:bar)`. Maybe not useful in this case if you're not using ActiveSupport, but others who find this page might be interested to know this.