# How to run 2 commands only if first succeeded in ruby?

Tags: ruby, command, logical-operators

I would like to run 2 commands in ruby but only if the first one succeeds.

In bash I would use `&&` operator. I have tried this one and `and` keyword but `&&` has thrown an error and `and` operator didn't works as expected.

The example I want to use it for:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
puts "asd" and puts "xxx"
```

executed as:

```
$ ./asd.rb
asd
```

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: Sorry I have updated it now

Comment: what you want is `puts "asd" \n puts "xxx"`

Comment: `puts` always returns `nil`, you have no way to know if it succeeded or not.

Comment: @toro2k Well this makes a lot of sense then... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `and` has lower precedence than `&&`.  Both use [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

First, note that `puts` always returns `nil`.  In ruby, `nil` is falsey.

```
2.2.0 :002 > puts "asdf"
asdf
 => nil
```

Now we try your example:

```
2.2.0 :002 > puts "asd" and puts "xxx"
asd
 => nil
```

This is the same as:

```
puts("asd") && puts("xxx")
asd
 => nil
```

In both cases `puts "asd"` and `puts("asd")` return `nil` so `puts "xxx"` and `puts("xxx")` are never evaulated because `nil` is falsey and there is short-circuit evaulation being used.

You also tried `puts "asd" && puts "xxx"`, but this is a syntax error because of the higher precendence of the `&&` operator.

```
puts "asd" &&  puts "xxx"
SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
puts "asd" &&  puts "xxx"
                     ^
```

That's because `puts "asd" && puts "xxx"` is the same as `puts("asd" && puts) "xxx"`.

```
2.2.0 :012 > puts("asd" && puts) "xxx"
SyntaxError: (irb):12: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
puts("asd" && puts) "xxx"
                     ^
```

See also:  [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)