# Precedence of and/or versus method arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

Here are two tests:

```
if [1,2,3,4].include? 2 && nil.nil?
  puts :hello
end
#=>
```

and

```
if [1,2,3,4].include?(2) && nil.nil?
  puts :hello
end
#=> hello
```

The above tells me that `&&` has higher precedence than method arguments so it logically ands `2 && nil.nil?` which is true and passes that as an argument to include?.

However, there is this test:

```
if [1,2,3,4].include? 2 and nil.nil?
  puts :hello
end
#=> hello
```

So this is telling me that method arguments and '`and`' have the same precedence (or method args are higher than '`and`') since it passed 2 to include? before it processed 'and'.

Note: I understand that `&&` and `and` have different precedence.  The question is not regarding this but regarding `and` or `or` vs the arguments to a ruby method.

I can't find documentation that affirms this.  For instances, this doesn't mention method arguments at all: http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4 or http://romhack.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby_operators.

Could anyone explain this behavior?  Namely in that how does ruby know to pass values as arguments to a method vs. process operators?

Comment: As part of the parsing, and `and` and `&` have a different precedence. Once you start calling methods with no parentheses it gets pretty convoluted pretty quickly, but it'll stop thinking something is an argument at the first whitespace,  iirc. Or the other way around.

Comment: My rule of thumb to avoid this confusion: include the parentheses when calling methods with arguments even if they're not necessary and never use `and` or `or`. Ruby people tend to have a pathological fear of parentheses so using them gets me lots of dirty looks but I don't care, my code is readable rather than a confusing attempt at poetry.

Comment: + 1. Insofar as this aspect of Ruby's behavior is modeled on Perl, you may find Perl's operator-precedence chart to be helpful; see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity. That chart *does* include function calls -- which have different "leftward" and "rightward" precedence. (For example, `1 && foo 2 && 3` means `1 && (foo (2 && 3))` -- the function-call has higher precedence than the first `&&`, but lower precedence than the second `&&`.) Of course, for Ruby that chart is not even remotely authoritative.

Comment: My money is on all operators having precedence over method calls.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, but my final test proves otherwise.  It says that either A) method call arguments have the same precedence as the 'and' operator, or that B) method call arguments have higher precedence than the 'and' operator.

Comment: It's fortunate I placed only a small bet. btw, couldn't you have just written `true` rather than `nil.nil?`? Great question, btw.

Comment: @μ, yeah, yeah, yeah, but why?, why? why? (is OP getting those results).

Comment: @muistooshort, perhaps I should say, "'and' and 'or' one condemns, with that I concur, needless parens?, only maybe, there I'll demure, but let's not forget what still must be penned: it's insight I say, of that I am sure!"

Comment: From the table you have given you can see `#defined?` given in the precedence table. This is just a normal Ruby method defined in `Object` so you can just take this as the priority of method calls.

Answer (score 1):

As you said `&&` and `and` have different precedence, however the explanation for the following example:

```
if [1,2,3,4].include? 2 and nil.nil?
  puts :hello
end
#=> hello
```

is the binding strenght of the `and` as you can read here:
[Difference between "and" and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)

This basically explains that `2 and nil.nil?` will be evaluated as nil, however it will return 2 as can be seen in this example:

```
foo = :foo
bar = nil

a = foo and bar
# => nil
a
# => :foo

a = foo && bar
# => nil
a
# => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any documentation about method argument precedence, but one rule of thumb I use when seeing method arguments is to mentally strip the whitespace wherever possible in the arguments and still have the same expression. This normally gives me the precedence:

`[1,2,3,4].include? 2&&nil.nil?` is the same expression, but you cannot strip the whitespace in
`[1,2,3,4].include? 2 and nil.nil?` and therefore, the precedence is left to right ... I.e. Method argument is 2.

Anyway, the better question is why on earth would you write statements like this?

Omitting method parenthesis is only useful for code readability. However, your statements are hardly readable and makes one pause over the code and think about it more than he should. If I was to review code like this, I would definitely fail the code review due to poor readability.

In fact, many style guides explicitly state that most methods with arguments should be parenthesized (is this even a word ;). For example:
[Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-dsl-parens)

Comment: I agree with you.  This was in a code review and when I asked about it, I tried testing it out and discovered this behavior and I just wanted to gain understanding about the precedence of method arguments.  I don't use `and` ever and I knew that the code as it was with `&&` would not work so I was curious about why it worked with `and`.

Comment: Yep, using this code in production would be mental, but it does make an interesting discussion, which I think was point