# Ruby Boolean Operations

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

In Rails (so, Ruby), I need either x and y to be true or just a to be true:

```
(x && y) || a
```

I suspect I could write

```
x && y || a
```

But I don't know how Ruby's precedence works. I did some testing and I still wasn't certain (especially with the anomaly on line 3):

```
true | true & false    # => true
true || true && false  # => true
true or true and false # => false #huh?

true | false & true    # => true
true || false && true  # => true
true or false and true # => true
```

Bonus points* for the difference between `||` and `|` and `or` (and the `and` equivalents - I believe the English versions are banned in the Ruby styleguide).

But really my question is how to write `(x && y) || a` without brackets.

* bonus point are only imaginary because @sawa (in the comments below) is secretly Sheldon Cooper

Comment: While this is not an answer for your question, it might be worth reading [this article](http://www.elpassion.com/blog/ruby-gotchas/#crayon-5506f31c4d981979786739)

Comment: `( )` are not brackets (in American English). They are parentheses.

Comment: @sawa Maybe upvote and accept the best answer, upvote the next that explains what the bitwise operators are.

Comment: @YawBoakye I don't know if that is what the OP intended, but regardless of that, the OP should not write something like that.

Comment: @sawa I'm from South Africa where they're brackets and we spell colour with a "u" and have bonus points.

Comment: "But really my question is how to write (x && y) || a without brackets." - just write them so, `x && y || a`. `&&` is stronger than `||` so it'll evaluate first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> either x and y to be true or just a

Assuming I understand you correctly, I would write that as `(x && y) || a`, as you suggested in your question. Regardless of precedence, including the parenthesis makes it clear to others how the expression is intended to behave.

To answer your question though, yes you can omit the parenthesis in this case, as demonstrated by the test case `false && false || true #=> true` vs `false && (false || true) => false` which shows that `&&`'s precedence is at least equal to that that of `||` (it's actually higher precedence, as shown by `true || false && false #=> true`).

The main difference between `||` and `|` (and similarly, `&&` and `&`) with booleans in Ruby is that `|` is a method on the boolean classes, whereas `||` is a language-level boolean operator. This means that `||` supports short-circuit evaluation, whereas `|` does not. Additionally, `|` and `&` both have higher precedence than `&&` and `||`, (with `&` having the highest precedence), as shown by `false && false | true #=> false` and `true | false & false #=> true`.

**When doing boolean operations like you are now, `||` and `&&` are almost always what you want.**

As for the difference in precedence between `||` and `or` (or similar), that question has been asked several times already. You may want to look at [Difference between "and" and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1426826/1157054) and [Difference between "or" and || in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2083112/1157054), as they should answer your question in that regard. (The short answer is that `or` and `and` are statement-level operators, whereas `||` and `&&` are expression-level.)

Comment: I think the OP meant "either x and y to be true or just a (to be true)". There is omission.

Comment: @sawa Yeah, I thought that might be the case. Is that any different from the second case I listed?

Comment: You still don't seem to get it. Spelling out even fully would be "either [(both) x and y to be true] or [just a (to be true)]".

Comment: @sawa Ah, I get it. That's weird, I could've sworn the original question said "I need either x or y to be true or just a". One second while I edit...

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic comparison operators (`||` and `&&`) take precedence over assignment (`=`), while `&&` takes precedence over `||`. It's not the case with their English versions. They both have equal precedence and are lower than the assignment operator.

Comment: `|` and `&` are bitwise operators. `|` is the bitwise OR, `&` is the bitwise AND. They behave very differently, and I think that's not what you should be using at all.