# determine network segment of user based on IP with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a list of network segments, and would like my website to recognize what network segment users are connected to based on their IP address. This is so I can select their location automatically on my site vs them having to choose manually. Whats a good way or determining this?

So far I have the below.

To find the client IP address:

```
local_ip = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect('64.233.187.99', 1); s.addr.last }
```

My array of Network Segments:

```
network_segments = [
{"name"=>"Site 1", "starting_address"=>"192.168.168.1", "ending_address"=>"192.168.175.254"},
{"name"=>"Site 2", "starting_address"=>"192.168.184.1", "ending_address"=>"192.168.191.254"},
{"name"=>"Site 3", "starting_address"=>"192.168.176.1", "ending_address"=>"192.168.183.254"}
]
```

I've tried removing the periods from the IPs and looping through each network segment to see if ***local_ip*** is > ***starting_address*** and < the ***ending_address***, but this doesn't seem accurate. It should only return one name, and it returns all of them.

Is there a better way to see if the local_ip is in between any of my network segment IPs?

```
ip = local_ip.delete('.').to_i

network_segments.each do |seg|
   start_addr = seg['starting_address'].delete('.').to_i
   end_addr = seg['ending_address'].delete('.').to_i

    if ip > start_addr and ip < end_addr
      puts seg['name']
    end
end
```

Comment: There are gems that do this. I think this is one of them: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: thanks but seems more geared toward finding geographical location. i need to determine location based within a set of specific Network Segment IP addresses. the IPs are static, internal, and set by a Network Engineer. I don't need location based on public address.

Comment: Consider changing the title of your question, it seems to imply geographic location.

Comment: title updated, thanks

Comment: ah internally set ip addresses right. The geolocator does actually work on ip-address - it takes the given IP  and determines where you are located (not just a physical address). but if you're setting them yourself, then that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [IPAddr](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/IPAddr.html) class (represents an IP Address) instead of a string with dots removed.  IPAddr provides comparison operators which understand which addresses are greater/less than another.

```
require 'ipaddr'
# ...
local_ip = IPAddr.new(local_ip)
network_segments.each do |seg|
  if local_ip > IPAddr.new(seg['starting_address']) and local_ip < IPAddr.new(seg['ending_address'])
    puts seg['name']
  end
end
```

edit: Apart from the fact that your ranges go from 1..254 instead of 0..255, you could implement the checks using a netmask range, eg:

```
IPAddr.new("192.168.168.1/21").to_range.first.to_s       # => "192.168.168.0"
IPAddr.new("192.168.168.1/21").to_range.last.to_s       # => "192.168.175.255"
IPAddr.new("192.168.168.1/21").include?("192.168.170.1") # => true
IPAddr.new("192.168.168.1/21").include?("192.168.176.1") # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that IP addresses aren't reliably lexicographically comparable (i.e. as strings), consider using the [standard `IPAddr` module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html):

```ruby
require 'ipaddr'

a1 = '10.1.1.1'
a2 = '2.1.1.1'
a1 < a2 # => true (nope!)

i1 = IPAddr.new(a1)
i2 = IPAddr.new(a2)
i1 < i2 # => false (ok)
```

Also, note that is it a generally accepted best practice to [use `&&` instead of `and` for boolean logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby).