# "and" vs "&&" operator in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby) stack question,

> `and` is the same as `&&` but with lower precedence

And I understand this well. And I believe this question is not duplicate to the above question.

In my controller when executing the following code:

`user = user_email.present? && User.find_by(email: user_email)`

`user` variable holds the `active record object` for `User` model. And thus executing `user.valid_password? user_password` gave no error and test passed successfully.

But when I tried to replace `&&` with `and` the result is quite surprising.

When I tried with following code:

`user = user_email.present? and User.find_by(email: user_email)`

`user` variable holds the `boolean` value and thus executing `user.valid_password? user_password`gave following error:

> undefined method `valid_password?' for true:TrueClass

Can anyone please explain why this is happening.

Comment: It is happening because `and` has lower precenedce than assignment. Same applies to `or` in Ruby. Because of this, those 2 work more like control structures than operators, allowing you to do things like `do_something() or fail`, but is often confusing for new Ruby programmers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
user = user_email.present? and User.find_by(email: user_email)
```

is interpreted as:

```
(user = user_email.present?) and User.find_by(email: user_email)
```

and `present?` returns `true` or `false`, which is assigned to `user`.

Comment: So, that means `User.find_by(email: user_email)` will not take an effect if we use `and` operator ?

Comment: @SujitS It will not have any effect unless this single line is further part of a surrounding structure.

Comment: It is because, as was mentioned in the very beginning, "=" has a higher precedence than "and".

(user = user_email.present?)  and evaluation stops there because = has higher precedence.

Answer (score -3):

Your user variable have TrueClass. TrueClass have no "valid_password?" method. Thats why it happens to your code.

```
> a = true 
> a.valid_passowrd?
> undefined method `valid_password?' for true:TrueClass
```

Why it must works?

Comment: The OP already knows that *"`user` variable holds a boolean value"*, the question is "why?".

Comment: Becouse  class TrueClass have no "valid_password?" method
So to solve the problem I need more information about his task

Comment: The problem has already been solved. Thanks for your concern.