# What happens with further conditions if first one is `false`?

Tags: ruby

I often face the situation when if condition A (for example `!@object.nil?`) is `false`, condition B, when checked, can raise an error (for example `@object.some_method -> undefined method 'some_method' for nil:NilClass`).

I tested it in console, but could't get some full data.

1) Is it safe to use `and`/`&&` when if first conditional is `false`, second can lead into an error?

2) What about `or`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10648796/4664086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!@object.nil? && @object.some_method

@object && @object.some_method
```

Both of the above are valid patterns in Ruby. You will not get the "undefined method for nil" error, because the expression to the right of the `&&` is never evaluated if the expression to the left of it evaluates to `nil` (or `false`).

You can also accomplish this check using postfix `if` or `unless`:

```
@object.some_method if @object
```

or

```
@object.some_method unless @object.nil?
```

are both valid alternatives.

Regarding `or`:

Using `||` (Rubyists generally avoid the keyword `or` operator) will not protect you from the error, because when the expression on the left side of the `||` evaluates to `nil`, the interpreter will actually continue on and attempt to evaluate the expression on the right side.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

Second part of these lines will never be exected:

```
false && raise "this will never be raised"
true || raise "this will never be raised"
```

In your case, if you are using active support, you can do:

```
@object.try!(:some_method)
```

Comment: or `@object.respond_to?(:some_method)`