# Rails validations depending on the value that may be not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've got a service object which has several validations that validate two params. Everything works fine until these params are "". In this case, even though I validate their presence, later validations raise errors. How can I make my code validate the presence first and then, only if the values are present, continue the validations?

```
class SubscriptionPause
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :paused_from, :paused_till, :params, :id

  validates :paused_from, presence: true, allow_nil: true
  validates :paused_till, presence: true, allow_nil: true

  validate :paused_from_cant_be_later_than_subscription_ends
  validate :paused_from_cant_be_in_the_past
  validate :paused_till_is_later_than_paused_from

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
    @paused_form = params[:paused_from]
    @paused_till = params[:paused_till]
  end

  def create
    if valid?
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

  private

  def subscription
    @subscription || Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  def paused_from_cant_be_in_the_past
    if !paused_from.empty? && paused_from.to_date < Date.today
      errors.add(:paused_from, I18n.t("..."))
    end
  end

  def paused_till_is_later_than_paused_from
    if paused_from > paused_till
      errors.add :paused_from, I18n.t("...")
    end
  end

  def paused_from_cant_be_later_than_subscription_ends
    if !paused_from.empty? && subscription.expire_date < paused_from
      errors.add :paused_from, I18n.t("...")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: FYI you have a typo in the initialize method `@paused_f`or`m`

Comment: If the values are not present what should happen? Should the other validations be skipped or should the pause request fail?

Comment: @joewoodward other validations should be skipped and the presence error must be added to the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above, it sounds like you never want the from or till to be nil so remove `allow_nil: true`. Then just add a conditional to the other validations as suggested by Rahul

```
validates :paused_from, presence: true
validates :paused_till, presence: true

validate :paused_from_cant_be_later_than_subscription_ends, if: :params_present?
validate :paused_from_cant_be_in_the_past, if: :params_present?
validate :paused_till_is_later_than_paused_from, if: :params_present?

def params_present?
  paused_from.present? && paused_till.present?
end
```

P.S. don't use `and` over `&&` unless you know why (suggested by Rahul). `&&` is better in nearly all cases. [Difference between "and" and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
validate :paused_from_cant_be_later_than_subscription_ends, :if => :params_present?
validate :paused_from_cant_be_in_the_past, :if => :params_present?
validate :paused_till_is_later_than_paused_from, :if => :params_present?

def params_present?
  return params[paused_from].present? and params[paused_till].present?
end
```