# Ruby: if boolean true return first_name from same row (in csv file)

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm able to work this statement to a point but I'd like to add another outcome. How to get the statement to return a value from the same row (headed 'first_name') in the CSV if the boolean statement returns true?

[image: CSV File for example]

```
def customer_check(user_pin)

  x = false

  CSV.read('customers.csv', headers: true).any? do |row|
    x = true if row['pin'] == user_pin and row['work_here'] == "YES"
    yellow = row['first_name']

  if x == true then
    puts "Welcome back #{yellow}."
    sleep(1.5)
  else
    puts "login failed. Please try again in 3 seconds..."
    sleep(3.0)
    login_start
  end
    navigation_menu
end
```

Comment: You can refactor `x = true if row['pin'] == user_pin && row['work_here'] == "YES"` to `x = row['pin'] == user_pin && row['work_here'] == "YES"` and second, `if x == true then` to `if x` only.

Comment: Isn't there an extra `end` keyword in above code? Can you please fix the indentation? It will be more clear then.

Comment: Sorry all I have just updated the code. Hope it makes more sense. @Jagdeep the changes you proposed didn't seem to work out but maybe because the code was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are 100% sure the pins in your csv are unique you could try this

```
def customer_check(user_pin)

  user = CSV.read('customers.csv', headers: true).detect { |row| 
      row['pin'] == user_pin && row['work_here'] == "YES"
  }

  if user
    puts "Welcome back #{user['first_name']}."
    sleep(1.5)
  else
    puts "login failed. Please try again in 3 seconds..."
    sleep(3.0)
    login_start
  end

  navigation_menu

end
```

Variable `user` will be initialized as the corresponding row of the .csv for which the conditional is true. Otherwise it's value will be nil:

> `detect` method according to [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#detect-method):
>
> > Passes each entry in *enum* to block. Returns the first for which *block* is not false. If no object matches, calls *ifnone* and returns its result when it is specified, or returns *nil* otherwise.
> >
> > If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

Bear in mind that you might have to ensure that `row['pin']` matches your `user_id` data type as it may come in as a String in which case you'd have to `row['pin'].to_i == user_pin`

Comment: Another thing, I wouldn't really use `and` or `or` for logical operations in conditionals - [Difference between “and” and && in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

**How to get the statement to return a value from the same row (headed 'first_name') in the CSV if the boolean statement returns true?**

Running your code as is, Ruby expects a final "end" and raises this error:
`syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Adding another ending 'end' to your code will result in the `if x == true` block getting evaluated, but, note the indentation in the following code is arguably clearer. Using [this example .csv file](https://github.com/mixelpixel/stackoverflow/blob/master/ruby/customers.csv), this code will both print `Welcome back...` and `return` the first name if `x == true`:

```
require 'csv'

def customer_check(user_pin)

  x = false

  CSV.read('customers.csv', headers: true).any? do |row|
    x = true if row['customerNo'] == user_pin && row['lastName'] == "Dunbar"
    yellow = row['firstName']
    # The if/else clauses are indented within the CSV.read
    if x                                           # <-- "== true" is redundant
      # puts "Welcome back #{yellow}."             # you can lose "yellow" if you want to
      puts "Welcome back #{row['firstName']}."
      sleep(1.5)
      # return yellow                              # <-- RETURN VALUE
      return row['firstName']                      # <-- RETURN VALUE
    else  
      puts "login failed. Please try again in 3 seconds..."
      sleep(3.0)
      # login_start
    end
  # navigation_menu

  end

end

return_name = customer_check('1')                  # <-- prints "Welcome back John"
puts return_name                                   # <-- "John" is the RETURN VALUE
```

I'm not sure how you are using `login_start` or `navigation_menu` but i hope this helps to answer your question. If it helps, here's the [CSV doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Comment: apologies Mr Kennedy I updated the original questions. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @PaulThompson, no need to apologize! Don't forget to select an answer and vote for useful comments/answers :)