# Problem with boolean operators (and &&, ! not)

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between `3 == 3 and not("testing" == "testing" or "Ruby" == "Fun")` and `3 == 3 && !("testing" == "testing" or "Ruby" == "Fun")`?

The first one gives `true` and last one gives `false`. I thought that `and` is as same as `&&` and not is same as `!`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. On my machine, both variants return `false`. What version of Ruby do you use? Or are there parts missing in your example like an assignment?

Comment: Both code snippets should evaluate to `false` however `!` and `&&` have a higher precedence than `not` and `and`. So they're not exactly the same.

Comment: `&&` is a boolean operator whereas `and` is a control-flow operator. They are used in totally different contexts, e.g. `if this && that` vs. `do_this and return`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "and" and && in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby)