# Ruby iterator with a function. Return the first value from function without iterating the whole list

Tags: ruby

I have a array: `arr=[x1, x2, x3...]` and a function that returns a value based on the first `x` in `arr` that the function is truthy.

Essentially:

```
# my_x is the return of func() 
# with the first x in arr that func(x) is true
# and the entire arr array is not processed.

my_x=arr.ruby_magic{|x| func(x) } 

my_x should be equal to first true value return of func(x)
```

Suppose each `X` in `arr` is a regex pattern. Without having to run every regex, I want to return the caputure group from the first match.

In Python, I would write a generator with `next`. It will run each predicate until a truthy return then hand that value to `m`. If no truthy return, `None` is used as a default but that default could be anything:

```
import re 

patterns=[r"no match", r": (Value.*?pref)", r": (Value.*)", r"etc..."]

s=""" 
This is the input txt
This is a match if the other is not found: Value 1

This is the match I am looking for first: Value 1 pref

Last line.
"""

val_I_want=next(
        (m.group(1) for p in patterns 
            if (m:=re.search(rf'{p}', s))), None)
```

I have not found the equivalent in Ruby.

I could do an explicite loop:

```
# s in the same multiline string as above...

patterns=[/no match/, /: (Value.*?pref)/, /: (Value.*)/,/etc.../]

val_I_want=nil 
patterns.each{|p| 
    m=p.match(s)
    if m then
        val_I_want=m[1]
        break 
    end     
}
# val_I_want is either nil or 
# the first match capture group that is true
```

That is the functionality I want but that seems kinda wordy in comparison to the the Python generator.

I have tried `grep` with the first value being a predicate. But the probelm here is *entire* result array is generated prior to `next` being used:

```
patterns.grep(proc {|p| p.match(s)}) {|m| m.match(s)[1]}.to_enum
# can then use .next on that.
#BUT it runs though the entire array when all I want is the first

#<Enumerator: ["Value 1 pref", "Value 1"]:each>
```

I tried `find` but that returns the first pattern that is true, not the capture group:

```
> e=patterns.find{|p| p.match(s) }
=> /: (Value.*?pref)/

# Now I would have to rerun match with the pattern found to get the text
```

Ideas?

---

Thank you *so much* for the helpful ideas. I learned several new things in my Ruby kit bag.

After looking, trying several I think the best *for me* is combining Dogbert's `lazy.filter_map` with Stefans suggestion of `s[regex, 1]` for this:

```
val_I_want=patterns.lazy.filter_map { |p| s[p, 1] }.first
```

Interestingly, the syntax `s[p, 1]` does NOT support dynamic regexes inside the `[]` operator without parenthesis like so `(Regexp.new "#{p.to_s}(.*)")` which takeaway from the attractiveness.

I ended up using:

```
patterns.lazy.filter_map { |p| card.match("#{p}(.*)")&.[](1) }.first
```

But this works too:

```
patterns.find{ |p| m = card.match("#{p}(.*)") and break m[1] }
```

In a more general case, you can do:

```
def func(x)
  # silly function for show
  x*x
end     

arr=[1,3,5,6,7,8,9]

p arr.lazy.filter_map { |x| (fx=func(x))>30 ? [x,fx] : nil }.first
# [6, 36]
```

And a very honorable mention to engineersmnky's modification of my `.find` attempt:

```
val_I_want = patterns.find {|p| m = p.match(s) and break m[1] }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.lazy.filter_map { .. }.first`. This will not run the block for elements after the first truthy value is found.

```
irb> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].lazy.filter_map { |x| p x; x > 3 ? x * 2 : nil }.first
1
2
3
4
=> 8
```

This will return `x * 2` for the first `x` that's greater than 3. I added `p x;` to show that this code doesn't process the 5th element of the list.

---

The Regex example:

```
irb> regexes = [/(1)/, /(2)/, /(3)/]
=> [/(1)/, /(2)/, /(3)/]
irb> regexes.lazy.filter_map { |regex| p regex; regex.match("2")&.[](1) }.first
/(1)/
/(2)/
=> "2"
```

---

Using `String[Regexp, Integer]` syntax as suggested by @Stefan in a comment below:

```
regexes.lazy.filter_map { |regex| p regex; string[regex, 1] }.first
```

Demo:

```
irb> regexes = [/(1)/, /(2)/, /(3)/]
=> [/(1)/, /(2)/, /(3)/]
irb> string = "2"
=> "2"
irb> regexes.lazy.filter_map { |regex| p regex; string[regex, 1] }.first
/(1)/
/(2)/
=> "2"
irb> string = "4"
=> "4"
irb> regexes.lazy.filter_map { |regex| p regex; string[regex, 1] }.first
/(1)/
/(2)/
/(3)/
=> nil
```

Comment: `detect` will return the value of the array for which the block evaluates to a truthy value, not the value that the block evaluates to. In Rust there's `.find_map` for this but Ruby doesn't have a similar method AFAIK.

Comment: ...and `nil` is returned if there is no regex that produces a match.

Comment: This is awsome as well. Perfect use for the `&.` safe navigation but then you lost me on what `[](1)` is doing? Obviously getting the first capture group, but why does that work?

Comment: @dawg the method is [`MatchData#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D) and the argument is `1`. Generally this would be expressed as `obj[1]` which is a bit of sugar provided by the parser; however with safe navigation operator in the middle the call to the method must use the traditional method syntax of `method_name(args)`

Comment: For strings, there's `str[regex, 1]` which returns the 1st capture if regex matches.

Answer (score 3):

While @Dogbert's answer is probably preferential and more idiomatic ruby.

You could also combine your presented `each` loop and the use of `Enumerable#find` that you attempted, into the following:

```
val_I_want = patterns.find {|p| m = p.match(s) and break m[1] }
# Or more esoterically and about as golfish as I can get it 
#(modification inspired by @CarySwoveland's use of the ruby global $1)
val_I_want = patterns.find{s[_1]and break$1}
```

This works because:

1. `String#match` will return `nil` if no match exists
2. `and` has a lower precedence than assignment (so the assignment of `m` occurs before the right hand condition is evaluated)
3. `break` exits the loop with the return value provided `m[1]` in this case
4. `find` will return `nil` if no truthy value is present

Alternatively and closer to your original implementation (albeit a bit less attractive than the above)

```
val_I_want = patterns.find {|p| if m = p.match(s) then break m[1] end }
```

Comment: This is perfect! I reflexively replaced `and` with `&&` then [got a little lesson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10648796/298607) on Ruby precedence.

Comment: @dawg For future reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html

Comment: I think your first `find` block is exactly what I was looking for. Native and idiomatic and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the lowly [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.each do |rgx|
    s = "2"[rgx] && $1
    return s unless s.nil?
  end
  nil
end
```

```
doit([/(1)/, /(2)/, /(3)/, /(2)/]) #=> "2"
doit [/(1)/, /(3)/]                #=> nil
```

---

A second way is to employ the venerable [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`):

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.reduce(nil) { |memo, rgx| memo || ("2"[rgx] && $1) }
end
```

```
doit([/(1)/, /(2)/, /(3)/, /(2)/]) #=> "2"
doit [/(1)/, /(3)/]                #=> nil
```

All elements of `arr` are examined but `("2"[rgx] && $1)` is not computed once `memo` ceases to equal `nil`.

If desired, one could of course short-circuit the calculations by `break memo` or `return memo` once `memo` is not `nil`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, if I never saw `_1` again it would be too soon.