# How can I get a list of all available models from within a running Rails project, to say, from a console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

The method to walk through apps/models and look into each file for classes is not what I'm looking for

Comment: The difference is that not all models might be loaded. Some might have failed for some reason, though not having failed a project in general.

Comment: Can't you just try to load them then as you walk through?

Comment: I faced a strange case during a project's runtime which is in fact that some models seemed not to be loaded. For now, I've solved my problem. But first I wanted to investigate it and I needed a list of loaded models for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: [Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app/516605#516605)

For example:

```
Module.constants.select do |constant_name|
  constant = eval constant_name
  if not constant.nil? and constant.is_a? Class and constant.superclass == ActiveRecord::Base
    constant
  end
end
```

Comment: There's no such a way that I asked for among listed in there. Some do work properly, some don't. And no suitable method for my case.

Comment: This method most of all looks like a needed answer. But when I tried it on my project, it returned just a few of its models. I did not dive deep into why that's so.

Comment: It could be that you actually have to instantiate the model and that would be a bummer. Can't test that theory right now.

Comment: This method also returns just a couple of models either from within a console or from within a view. Even more, it returns different sets of models from different views. That means  that you're right -- the returned models list depends on context. The question turned out to be not so simple...