# ActiveRecord Global Callbacks for all Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, global

I have around 40 models in my RoR application. I want to setup a after_save callback for all models. One way is to add it to all models. Since this callback has the same code to run, is there a way to define it globally once so that it gets invoked for all models.

I tried this with no luck:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :do_something

  def do_something
    # .... 
  end
end
```

Same code works if I do it in individual models.

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use observers for this:

```
class AuditObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer      

  observe ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses)

  def after_save(record)
    AuditTrail.new(record, "UPDATED")
  end
end
```

In order to activate an observer, list it in the config.active_record.observers configuration setting in your config/application.rb file.

```
config.active_record.observers = :audit_observer
```

**Note**

In Rails 4, the observer feature is removed from core. Use the https://github.com/rails/rails-observers gem.

Comment: Great, thanks! 

so I need to add all the models to "observe", right?

I hope there would be way to dynamically fetch the list of Models and pass it to "observe"?

Thanks again.

Comment: I just found this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: That's cool. I think we need to add this line before the "observe" to make sure all models are loaded:

Dir.glob(RAILS_ROOT + '/app/models/*.rb').each { |file| require file }

Please correct me if I am wrong, or if there is a better to make sure all models are loaded.

Comment: If all your models are in the `models` directory this should work. Try it out and see. Should be pretty straight forward. Simply print the result of ` ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses)` inside the `AuditObserver` class.

Comment: Is there any Rails 4 alternative coz this code is not working in rails 4 and yes I have added observer gem

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, using Rails 4 and rails-observers 0.1.2. But I found you can just use `observe ActiveRecord::Base` and it will observe subclasses when they are defined (no need for eager loading or inspecting subclasses or descendants).

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty late on this one, but in case someone else is using Rails 3 and finds this, then this response might help.

Some models might not be loaded when the observer is loaded. The documentation says that you can override observed_classes, and that way you can get the subclasses of active record dynamically.

```
class AuditObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def self.observed_classes                 
    ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses)    
  end
end
```

Comment: This is really cool, but I'd encourage using `ActiveRecord::Base.descendants` to avoid the private method call.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.after_save do
   ...
end
```

Is there a problem I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @harish's answer and in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712838/2226338):

```
class AuditObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    observe ActiveRecord::Base.descendants

    def after_save(record)
        ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works pretty well for me in 2.3.8:

```
class AudiObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :'ActiveRecord::Base'
  #
  # observe methods...
  #
end
```