# Reading all models in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to detect all the models used in a Rails app that have database tables? I've tried to detect all models in a Rails application by reading all the models off of the app/models directory and simply read all the files in that directory. However, I do not think this is the best approach and have spent a considerable amount of time researching this but I haven't gotten a better answer yet. Can anyone help me with this. Many thanks!

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app

Comment: Thanks Doon. I've tried this method before and I was wondering if there is a better method.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are using ActiveRecord. If you are, here is how you go about getting a list of all ActiveRecord::Base subclasses:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses
```

You can also do the following:

```
dbmodels = []
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module){ |m| dbmodels << m if m.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base) && m != ActiveRecord::Base }
```

`dbmodels` should now contain all your ActiveRecord::Base models.

Keep in mind that in your development environment you won't get a full list of subclasses unless they have been loaded/used, so I would recommend performing this in your production environment instead, that way you can ensure that all your models have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure that all the models are loaded:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

In Rails 3, the ideal way to find all ActiveRecord descendants is with `descendants`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
```

Then, select those with a table:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.select(&:table_name)
```

The basis for this was pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712838/15585.