# Deleting all records in a database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I delete all records in one of my database tables in a Ruby on Rails app?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to it without SQL you should be able to use delete_all.

```
Post.delete_all
```

or with a criteria

```
Post.delete_all "person_id = 5 AND (category = 'Something' OR category = 'Else')"
```

See [here](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000345) for more information.

The records are deleted without loading them first which makes it very fast but will break functionality like counter cache that depends on rails code to be executed upon deletion.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you've got associations with :dependent => :destroy, or anything that needs to be cleaned up upon deletion, you'll probably want Post.destroy_all - though it is much slower. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class

Comment: This answer assumes that the table has a model associated with it. The OP didn't specify this - what if the table is a join table?

Comment: @BradWerth whether or not it is considered by some to be good or bad style, I'm just saying it is feasible that a Rails db has tables that aren't `ActiveRecord` models. The question asks about deleting record from a 'table'  and I'm just pointing or the assumption held in the answer.

Comment: I have same query as @Toby1Kenobi 's.

Answer (score 34):

To delete via SQL

`Item.delete_all # accepts optional conditions`

To delete by calling each model's destroy method (expensive but ensures callbacks are called)

`Item.destroy_all # accepts optional conditions`

All [here](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Answer (score 26):

if you want to completely empty the database and not just delete a model or models attached to it you can do:

```
rake db:purge
```

you can also do it on the test database

```
rake db:test:purge
```

Answer (score 7):

If you mean delete every instance of all models, I would use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map(&:classify)
  .map{|name| name.constantize if Object.const_defined?(name)}
  .compact.each(&:delete_all)
```

Comment: Prefer `select` whenever you need to use an if expression inside a block, this way you avoid having to chain the compact method to remove nil elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
BlogPost.find_each(&:destroy)
```

Comment: This is great for low memory circumstances.

Comment: This is the only answer that takes memory consumption into account.

Comment: Omg, why to make a loop for this... no sense. just delete all records DELETE FROM table, Model.delete_all

Comment: @John why one single query consumes more memory than a loop of queries?

Comment: @Imnl Each iteration instantiates a new instance of the model in question so that it can process the callbacks for the delete method.

Comment: @John I will execute the equivalent callbacks only, still doesnt have sense for me to perform all those queries to a db separately, it will take a lot more time.

Comment: @lmnl You realize this batches them in groups of 1000 by default? That was the point of my original comment about memory. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each.

Comment: @John i usually use find_each, but not for destroying groups of elements, that was de point of the question. find_each is a good tool but its not good for this case.

Comment: @imnl if you have a low memory server with 2 billion records that you want to delete...

Answer (score 2):

If your model is called BlogPost, it would be:

```
BlogPost.all.map(&:destroy)
```

Comment: this will fetch every single BlogPost and load it into a Ruby array before destroying them.

Comment: Depends on the ORM. Datamapper wouldn't do that because you're not requesting anything about each model. And here's a Mongoid stacktrace that shows it doesn't select any fields before destroying each entry: `MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=a_database collection=nothings selector={} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3378ms)`

Comment: since it's a rails question, and the asker hasn't said which ORM he's using, we should assume ActiveRecord

Answer (score 2):

More recent answer in the case you want to delete every entries in every tables:

```
def reset
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each { |c| c.delete_all unless c == ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration  }
end
```

More information about the `eager_load` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712838/1939604).

After calling it, we can access to all of the descendants of `ActiveRecord::Base` and we can apply a `delete_all` on all the models.

Note that we make sure not to clear the SchemaMigration table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have model with relations, you need to destroy models that are related as well.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to achieve this:-

1. Want to delete all data from the table

```
Post.delete_all
```

2. Want to delete specific data from the table, then the right way to do it is

```
Post.where(YOUR CONDITIONS).delete_all
# this above solution is working in Rails 5.2.1, delete_all don't expect any parameter
# you can let me know if this works in different versions.

# In the older version, you might need to do something like this:-
Post.delete_all "Your Conditions"
```

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me, added this route below in routes.rb

```
get 'del_all', to: 'items#del_all' # del_all is my custom action and items is it's controller

def del_all #action in ItemsController
 if Item.any? 
  Item.destroy_all
  redirect_to items_url, notice: "Items were destroyed." 
 else  
  redirect_to items_url, notice: "No item found here." 
 end     
end
```

According to documentation:

> 2.5 Singular Resources - Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show the >profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use a singular >resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the show action: get 'profile', to: 'users#show'