# List all Models in inheritance tree beginning from ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, list, inheritance, models, descendant

I am currently very confused by using `descendants` for ActiveRecord::Base-Objects.
I have browsed the internet and tested all solutions but none of them fits my needs.

What i want to do: Get an Array of all subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base, including subclasses of these subclasses, e.g.

```
Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
ChildEntity < Entity

Property < ActiveRecord::Base
```

My current problems: ActiveRecord::Base.descendants does NOT list all the classes inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.
Perhaps the fault is on my side: here my code.

```
 def all_entities
   rec_all_entities(ActiveRecord::Base)
 end

 def rec_all_entities(motherEntity)
    logger.debug("mother: " + motherEntity.to_s + " descendants: " + motherEntity.descendants.to_s)
    motherEntity.descendants.each do |childEntity|
      rec_all_entities(childEntity)
    end
 end
```

For debbuging purpose I'm just printing out.
I'm using Rails 3.

I think the fault must lie in my code. I'm calling the method currently just in the view with `<% all_entities %>`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: as I can see, ActiveRecord::Base.descendants should list all descendants (even sub-subclasses). But anyhow it doesnt collect all descendants - the maximum is 4 entities - my model has 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app)

Answer (score 7):

This worked well for me.  Also, taken from [Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app)

```
> Rails.application.eager_load!
> ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in development mode you must touch each model before it will be picked up by `desendants`

Taken from [Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app)