# ActiveRecord::Base.send(:descendants) doesn't return all models unless touched

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

***Update:*** *This problem no longer exists in Rails 3.2*

I am trying to get an array containing all the models in my rails 3 application. I am trying:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:descendants)
```

for the same. A similar discussion happened in the question: [Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app). As pointed out in one of the answers, we need to touch the models for the models to show up. That is precisely the problem I am facing.

There are more than a dozen models in my rails app, but

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:descendants)
```

returns an array of size two. The array has just User and  ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session models. I don't get the other models untill I touch the model by touching, say invoking `Comment.new`
How can I get all the models listed without touching all the models?

Another additional piece of information that might be useful is that I am using devise for authentication. Maybe devise is doing things in a desired way as far as User model is concerned and I am not doing those things with the other models.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the models first:

```
Dir[Rails.root + "app/models/**/*.rb"].each do |path|
    require path
end
```

Comment: I found this still necessary when I tried to get the list of my models within an initializer

Answer (score 5):

If **cache_classes** is on (by default it's on in development, not in production), run this first:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```