# Rails & ActiveRecord: Appending methods to models that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a standard ActiveRecord model with the following:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  custom_method :first_field, :second_field
end
```

At the moment, that custom_method is picked up by a module sent to ActiveRecord::Base. The functionality basically works, but of course, it attaches itself to *every* model class, not just MyModel. So if I have MyModel and MyOtherModel in the same action, it'll assume MyOtherModel has custom_method :first_field, :second_field as well.

So, my question is: How do I attach a method (eg: def custom_method(*args)) to *every* class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, but not by attaching it to ActiveRecord::Base itself?

Any ideas appreciated.

===

## Edit

The custom_method is currently attached to ActiveRecord::Base by the following:

```
module MyCustomModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(self)
  end

  def custom_method(*args)
    # Zippity doo dah - code goes here
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, MyCustomModule)
```

Comment: Sounds like the key is what does `custom_method` do?

Comment: Opens up ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper --> fields_for & appends args from custom_method(*args) to the top of any form_for (wrapped in h1 tag). …Effectively a useless gem, but I'm trying to find my feet re: gem creation.

Comment: I think we'd need to see exactly what it's doing in order to conjecture why what is being done applies to all models (although it seems that a custom form builder might be more appropriate here)

Comment: Why not define a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, and have your models inherit from that?  Or is this something that you want completely hidden so that other developers can keep inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base and get the functionality without requesting it explicitly?

Comment: Hi Marc - cheers for the response. I was tempted by that, but yes - ideally I'd like the gem user to require no more input than appending the 'custom_method' line. I have vague memories of some sort of hook for appending instance methods to inherited classes(?), but maybe I just dreamt it up. Any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I woud like to see the module you are including and how you are attaching attaching the method.  You have strayed into the land of meta programming and I think what you have done is attached the methods to the base class, you should be attaching the methods to the meta class. check this out: http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-metaprogramming.html#h5

Comment: Cheers Ben. Added attachment process above. Meta might be the next step, but I was hoping/thinking there was some sort of simple hook on initialization that could add methods to any inherited class. ...Starting to think I may have hallucinated it. ;-)

Comment: If you were to call define_method from inside custom_method that would only add methods to the model in question

Comment: Actually - cheers, yeah - define_method might be easier than I'd thought. I'm just reading up on .descendants mentioned below...if that fails, define_method might be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about descendants?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
```

You have to be sure to touch the models before calling it.

See excellent discussion here:

[Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app)

I concur with the commentors above that you may want to consider adding your methods to the meta class, or an intermediary class, or a Module mixin.

Comment: Excellent - I suspect that's exactly what I was thinking of. (But have to run out before I can try it - back in a few hours)