# Iterating Over Rails Model Classes with Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, iteration

In an application there are many models with polymorphic associations defined like:

```
has_many :mentions, :as => :mentionable, :dependent => :destroy
```

In a library class all mentionable models are collected for later iterating.

```
mentionables = Model1.all + Model2.all + Model3.all ...
```

This works but it is just static which is not desirable for a library code. Bottom statement would be much more intuitive hovever it won't work.

```
mentionables = Mentionable.all
```

Is there an API in Rails to iterate over models with Polymorphic relations defined with ':as => ...' directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two questions in here and I'll try my best to answer both of them. First, you'd need a way to list all of the models in your Rails application. There are methods offered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app) question, and I prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712838/403664) (by [sj26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158252/sj26)).

```
# Really depends on how your classes are loaded, usually environment specific.
Rails.application.eager_load!
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
```

After, you need to parse the model associations to determine if they have an :as @option assigned, and pull out the associated class name. This is assuming that your association has been created as such:

```
class Mentionee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mentions, :as => :mentionable, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'Mentionable'
end
```

You can do this using the [reflect_on_all_associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) method (there is probably a more ruby-esque way to write this):

```
Mentionee.reflect_on_all_associations.select {|a| a.options[:as] == :mentionable }
```

Which will return the polymorphic class model for Mentionable. To join these up, you could do something as follows (untested!):

```
Rails.application.eager_load!

mentionables = []

ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |descendent|
  mentionables << descendent.reflect_on_all_associations.select{|a| a.options[:as] == :mentionable}
end

mentionables.each do |mentionable|
  # Do your work here
end
```