# Rails console display all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way in the `rails console` to display all rails models?

Something like this:

```
Models.all
```

which results on this:

```
[Customer, Site, Page, Download]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a collection of all the Models in your Rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516579/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-collection-of-all-the-models-in-your-rails-app)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses
```

This will return an array, so to get the name of the models only, you'd need to run:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.map(&:name)
```

Comment: No need for `send`, `#subclasses` is public.

Comment: you don't need `send` .. it is a public method

Comment: Is there any abbreviation for the `ActiveRecord::Base` snippet? Everytime I need something from the base layer, do I need to use this?

Comment: Does this actually work at all times? When I try this, some models are not included until I use them in the code, and it includes some non-model classes that apparently do something with `has_and_belongs_to_many`. For example, I get [`User`, `User::HABTM_Agencies`], then I invoke `Agency`, then I get [`User`, `User::HABTM_Agencies`, `Agency`, `Agency::HABTM_Users`]

Comment: This only works with loaded files. So in a development environment you'll only get a subset of the models. This is not a problem in production since models are eagerloaded. A possible solution would be to run `Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/*.rb"].each {|f| puts f; require File.basename f}` prior to running subclasses.

Comment: The best answer is found in an answer to a very similar question, which works on Rails 3 to 6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712838/3577922
Note this accepted answer does not work on Rails 5+ (the question is tagged for Rails 4).

Answer (score 6):

Just run:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried both the answers above, It does not work as expected. I got this result,

```
["User", "HABTM_Roles", "ApplicationRecord", "PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity", "ApplicationRecordGlobal", "HABTM_Users", "UserSync"]
```

What worked for me was,

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
ApplicationRecord.subclasses.map(&:name)
```

Comment: I think the origonal answer is for an older version of rails. I'm using rails `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.5'` and this worked for me. Nice find!

Answer (score 1):

if you run `rails c` with `-e production`, then

```
ApplicationRecord.subclasses
ApplicationRecord.subclasses.map(&:name)
```

if you run `rails c` in development, you need to run `eager_load` before above command

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

for all models have inherited from `ApplicationRecord` and `ApplicationRecord` inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`. 
and `eager_load!` will load all Models, but in development environment `eager_load` are false. you can find this config in `config/environments/development.rb`